# Why, when casting a short[] to char* is the array reversed?

Tags: c++, casting, char, endianness, short

For the following code:

```
short shortArray [] = { ( 'B' << 8 ) + 'A', ( 'D' << 8 ) + 'C', ( 'F' << 8 ) + 
'E', 'G' };
cout << (char*)shortArray;
```

The output is:

> ABCDEFG

Can someone explain to me the way in which this works?

Comment: research topic - endian

Comment: Downvoters - explain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression `( 'B' << 8 ) + 'A'` has a result of type `int`, will be equal to `'B'*256 + 'A'`.

When converted to a `short` (assuming a `short` is represented as two 8-bit bytes) this value is represented by the pair of bytes `AB`, where the `A` is the least significant byte.  On a little-endian machine, the least significant byte occurs first in memory  (i.e. the `'A'` is left-most, and the next byte is `'B'`).    On a big-endian machine, the `'B'` will be left-most.

The output you describe suggests your host architecture is little-endian.

Intel processors are all little-endian.  Historically, a range of CPUS including Motorola 68000 series processors, PowerPC, and Sparc (from Sun Microsystems) were all big-endian.      Network byte order (used to communicate data over a network) is big-endian.

Note:  for sake of discussion, I'm ignoring the fact your code as shown has undefined behaviour.  The streaming operator `<<` which accepts a `char *` ASSUMES the presence of a terminating `char` with value `'\0'`.   Your code does not ensure that terminator is present.

Answer (score 4):

A short is 16 bits and a char is 8. 
So one short can hold two characters in it.

The `( 'B' << 8 ) + 'A'` portion is shifting the value of 'B' by 8 bits and adding it to A. So now each half of the short is holding the ASCII code of a different character. In this case A and B.

Casting it to char* now makes it so the compiler will interpret the array as a string (which is just an array of characters) and you get that output

Comment: It's also important that the last character is followed by a zero byte.

And, the code is not portable, it will produce different output on other platforms.

Comment: `short` and `char` are *typically* 16 and 8 bits, respectively. And you don't mention endianness, which is what the OP was asking about.